# Unexpected result from IIF and ISNULL

Tags: ms-access

When using the code below on the record I am evaluating, NA is returned, which is what I want as [actual_ssd] (in this case) is null

```
Switch(
[Comm_Type]="Maya",CVDate(DateAdd("m",6,[actual_ssd])),
[Comm_Type]="Sapphire",IIf([Tariff_length]=12,CVDate(DateAdd("m",12,[actual_ssd])),CVDate(DateAdd("m",24,[actual_ssd]))),
[Comm_Type]="Cobalt",IIF(ISNULL([actual_ssd]),"NA","Test")
)
```

However, I want [actual_ssd] returned if [actual_ssd] is not null, but when I change my code to :-

```
Switch(
[Comm_Type]="Maya",CVDate(DateAdd("m",6,[actual_ssd])),
[Comm_Type]="Sapphire",IIf([Tariff_length]=12,CVDate(DateAdd("m",12,[actual_ssd])),CVDate(DateAdd("m",24,[actual_ssd]))),
[Comm_Type]="Cobalt",IIF(ISNULL([actual_ssd]),"NA",[actual_ssd])
)
```

...Access returns #Error in the query results.

Can anyone confirm why this is happening (where the [Comm_Type] is "Cobalt") ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you test it on a record that should return "Test"?

Comment: I just did, and [actual_ssd] is returned

Comment: Wait.  Shouldn't it only return either "NA" or "Test" in your working version?

Comment: No - the "final" version should return NA or [actual_ssd]. The version that returns NA where [actual_ssd] is null is my top piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix dates and strings, and indeed no need for CVDate:

```
Switch(
[Comm_Type]="Maya",DateAdd("m",6,[actual_ssd]),
[Comm_Type]="Sapphire",DateAdd("m",IIf([Tariff_length]=12,12,24),[actual_ssd]),
[Comm_Type]="Cobalt",IIf([actual_ssd] Is Null,"NA", Format([actual_ssd],"yyyy-mm-dd"))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct format in a query is

```
IIf([actual_ssd] Is Null,"NA",[actual_ssd])
```

IsNull() Only works in VBA

Comment: This also returns #Error

Comment: Then you have something else wrong - that syntax definitley works.
Try it on it's own with a single field. Expr1: IIf([YourField] Is Null,"flobble","Not Flobble")

Comment: `IsNull` works perfectly well in a query, like any other function.

Comment: I'm sure many moons ago I had issues with that syntax, but I'm obviously wrong! For some reason I'm sure there's additional overhead / problem to using it in a query though. Maybe it's when it's converted to SQL